# Javascript Pop-Up WIndow Open Function

Tags: asp.net, javascript, popupwindow

I am using the following JS function to open a pop-up window to display another website:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function link()
{
   window.open("www.google.com")
}

onClick="Link()"
```

The URL in the above example is just for testing.  I actually intend on replacing the URL with a text value from a listbox, which is in the form of a URL.  Anyway, when ever I start the debugger in Visual Studio, and execute the onClick, the pop-up window opens and gives me a page stating that there is a server error.  Specifically, `Server error in '/' application... resource cannot be found`.  Also, I notice that my URL is placed as follows: `http://localhost:49456/www.google.com`.  I thought this function would give me a pop-up window with Google as the website.  Is this a Visual Studio debugger issue, is my code wrong, or am I using the code in the wrong context?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to specify http:// in the url eg

```
window.open("http://google.com");
```

without that protocol specified, the browser will think the URL is relative to the current document.

Comment: Thank you - I feel like such an idiot.  Earlier, I was using "http//:", and it was not working so I decided to ask this question.  Thank you Andy E

Comment: No worries, more people than you'd think have fallen into that trap, me included :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `http://` to your domain, i.e. `http://www.google.com`.

Comment: Thank you - Earlier I kept typing "http//:" and not realizing that the URL format was wrong.  Thanks Josh,